# Constant instance in a static class

Tags: c#, class, static, constants

I am tying to make a Global variable class, here is my code

```
public static class GLOBALVAR
{
    public static const Color DIFFRENCECOLOR = System.Drawing.Color.LightSalmon;
    public static const Color NOMATCHCOLOR = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;     
}
```

but this does not want to work and I get this error

```
The type 'System.Drawing.Color' cannot be declared const
```

Is there a way to make this work.

Comment: have you tried `readonly` instead of `const`?

Comment: nope did not know that was a command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `readonly` instead

```
public static readonly Color DIFFRENCECOLOR = System.Drawing.Color.LightSalmon;
```

the `readonly` keyword means that your variable, `DIFFRENCECOLOR` can only be modified in the constructor of it's class,  `GLOBALVAR`.

It's normally used for when you want to declare a "constant" at runtime, but it works for this purpose too.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx